# Reading a datasheet for power requirements - regulator vs positive supply

Tags: power, voltage

I'm trying to interpret the attached datasheet to figure out how much power to give this sound board from adafruit:

https://www.adafruit.com/product/2220

I was hoping that the sound board could share the same power supply as 3 or 4 of these Intel Tinytile Accelerometers (datasheet also below):

https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/boardsandkits/curie/intel-curie-module-datasheet.pdf

Which number do I use for voltage from these datasheets?

Sound board datasheet:

[image]

Tinytile Datasheet:

[image]

Comment: the linked adafruit page says 3 V to 5.5 V ... the curie datasheet says it uses two power supplies, 1.8 V and 3.3 V

Comment: The Intel datasheet you linked is for a computing module, not for an accelerometer, and it doesn't have the word "tinytile" in it anywhere.